# Separating an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let’s suppose that $x, y$ are independent variables. If we have an integral such as

$$\int^{a}_{b} f(x-y) + g(x+y)dx$$

Can we split the integral into something of this form?

$$I(a,b) = \int_{a+y}^{b+y} f(t_{-}) \,\mathrm{d}t_{-} + \int_{a-y}^{b-y} g(t_{+}) \,\mathrm{d}t_{+}$$

Where $t_{\pm} = x\pm y$.

Comment: the terms are other integrals on f and g

Comment: Yes, but given how [bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) in integrals work you can just write $t$ instead of $t_\pm$ throughout.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to split the integral straightforwardly thanks to the linearity of the integral, namely
$$
I(a,b) := \int_a^b f(x-y) + g(x+y) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b f(x-y) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_a^b g(x+y) \,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
before translating the variables, i.e. $t_\pm = x \pm y$, hence
$$
I(a,b) = \int_{a+y}^{b+y} f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t + \int_{a-y}^{b-y} g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = F(b+y)-F(a+y) + G(b-y)-G(a-y)
$$
So, your splitting was correct, but you forgot to adapt the boundaries in the process.